# JSON Store fails intermittently in MobileFIrst hybrid app

Tags: android, json, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

We're trying to store a list of tasks in `JSONStore` and retrieve it as user clicks on a `fetch` button.

Observed behavior: We see that intermittently, `JSONStore` throws an `exception` and won't fetch the stored tasks at all. Same source code, when re-deployed works fine. Meaning, tasks are stored and fetched as expected.

Exception thrown message is `{"src":"find","err":22,"msg":"INVALID_SEARCH_FIELD","col":"CollectionTasksName","usr":"jsonstore","doc":{},"res":{}}`

Our writing and reading functions are below:

```
/**
* Function to add data to JSONStore collection
* @param collName: Collection name to add to
* @param dataToStore: data to store
* @param flag: flag for operation, if CLEAR, collection is cleared before adding the new data
* @param returnFunc: callback function for results handling 
*/
function Storage_add(collName,dataToStore,flag,returnFunc) {
WL.Logger.debug('SU: Storage add function called.');
console.log('SU: Storage add function called.');

var result = {'result': true};
var collections = {};
collections[collName] = {
        searchFields: {'id': 'string', 'processId' : 'string'}
};
var addFunc = function(collectn,data2Store,returnFunc) {
    WL.JSONStore.init(collections)
    .then(function() {
        WL.Logger.debug('Inside addFunc while adding to collection:'+collName);
        console.log('Inside addFunc while adding to collection:'+collName);
        WL.JSONStore.get(collName).add(data2Store, {push:true})
            .then(function (dataAdded) {
                WL.Logger.debug('Data added to the collection '+collName+'--Success');
                console.log('Data added to the collection '+collName+'--Success');
                returnFunc({'result': true});
            })
            .fail(function (errorObject) {
                // Handle failure for any of the previous JSONStore operations (init, add).
                WL.Logger.debug('Error adding data to the collection:'+collectn);
                console.log('Error adding data to the collection:'+collectn);
                returnFunc({'error':'Error adding the data'});
            });     
    })
    .fail(function (errobject) {
        WL.Logger.debug(errobject.toString());
        console.log(errobject.toString());
        returnFunc({'error':'JSONStore Error adding the data'});
    });
};
if(flag=='CLEAR') {
    WL.JSONStore.init(collections)
    .then(function() {
        WL.Logger.debug('With flag clear, opened collection:'+collName);
        console.log('With flag clear, opened collection:'+collName);
        WL.JSONStore.get(collName).removeCollection()
            .then(function () {
                WL.Logger.debug('Cleared collection --Success');
                console.log('Cleared collection --Success');
                // Handle success.
                addFunc(collName,dataToStore,returnFunc);
            })
            .fail(function (errorObject) {
                // Handle failure for any of the previous JSONStore operations (init, add).
                WL.Logger.debug('Error clearing collection:'+collName);
                console.log('Error clearing collection:'+collName);
                returnFunc({'error':'Error clearing the data'});
            });     
    });

} else {
    WL.Logger.debug('flag is not set as clear. About to call addFunc');
    console.log('flag is not set as clear. About to call addFunc');
    addFunc(collName,dataToStore,returnFunc);
}
   }
```

Reading function:

```
/**
* Function to fetch a collection data in array form using its name
* @param collName
* @param returnFunc: callback function for results handling
*/
function Storage_getArray(collName,returnFunc) {
console.log('SU: Storage get collection Array called for Collection:'+collName);
WL.Logger.debug('SU: Storage get collection Array called for Collection:'+collName);
var returnArray = [];

var collectionName = collName;
var JSONStoreCollections = {};
JSONStoreCollections[collectionName] = {};
JSONStoreCollections[collectionName].searchFields = {'id': 'string', 'processId' : 'string'};

var funcRes = function(res) {
    WL.Logger.debug('SU: Inside funcRes. No. of results:'+res.length);
    console.log('no. of results:'+res.length);
    WL.Logger.debug('res stringified:'+JSON.stringify(res));
    console.log('res stringified:'+JSON.stringify(res));
    if (res.length >= 1) {
        console.log('res has values.');
        $.each(res, function (index, val) {
            returnArray.push(val.json); //push values here
        });
    }
    WL.Logger.debug('SU: About to returnArray with length:'+returnArray.length);
    console.log('About to returnArray with length:'+returnArray.length);
    returnFunc(returnArray);
};

WL.Logger.debug('SU: About to start Collection '+collName+'. collections var:'+JSON.stringify(JSONStoreCollections));
console.log('SU: About to start Collection '+collName+'. collections var:'+JSON.stringify(JSONStoreCollections));
WL.JSONStore.init(JSONStoreCollections)
.then(function () {
          //WL.Logger.debug('ts Init done');
        WL.Logger.debug('SU: Collection init done. about to find all');
        console.log('SU: Collection init done. about to find all');
      return WL.JSONStore.get(collName).findAll();
 })
.then(funcRes)
.fail(function (err) {
        WL.Logger.debug('SU: Error caught for JSONStore init for collection:'+collName+'. err:'+err.toString());
        console.log('SU: Error caught for JSONStore init for collection:'+collName+'. err:'+err.toString());
        var retErr = {"error": "JSONStore"};
        returnFunc(err);
});
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what version of MobileFirst Platform you are using? Which functions are tied to what buttons. You said that the fetch function is tied to a function so what about the add? Also, what is the order of the execution such as do you press the `add` button before `fetch`?

Comment: srujan reddy, please reply.

Comment: @srujan reddy are you still experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be a defect in the product and is handled as part of the support ticket/PMR number 28639,756,000. A fix will be available in future iFix releases if need be.

Comment: Is there an iFix now (as you mentioned above) to address this issue? if so what is the iFix no please? Thanks.